# How to replace non numerical values in a dataset with R

Tags: r

I have a dataset who looks like this:

```
Date          Electricity
janv-90             23
juin-90             24
juil-90             34
janv-91             42
juin-91             27
juil-91             13
```

But I want it looking like that:

```
Date          Electricity
190             23
690             24
790             34
191             42
691             27
791             13
```

Note that my dataset goes from 90 to 10 (namely 1990 to 2010).

Comment: You can transform Date using `as.Date(df$Date)` and you may have to give it some formatting argument (I believe `as.Date(df$Date, '%b-%y')`). Once that's done you should be able to render the date in your desired format. I'm a bit unsure why you'd want that format for a date, but that's not my business.

Answer (score 0):

We can just use `match`, `substr` and `paste` to get the expected output

```
df$Date <- as.numeric(paste0(match(substr(df$Date, 1, 4), month.abb), substring(df$Date, 6)))
df
#    Date Electricity
# 1  190          23
# 2  690          24
# 3  790          34
# 4  191          42
# 5  691          27
# 6  791          13
```

---

Or using `tidyverse` by separating the 'Date' column into two columns ('Date' and 'val') by the `-` delimiter, then `match` the 'Date' with the `mon_ab` from the `locale()` and finally `unite` the 'Date' and 'val' columns together

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
separate(df, Date, into = c("Date", "val")) %>%
       mutate(Date = match(Date, sub("\\.$", "", locale("fr")[[1]]$mon_ab))) %>% 
       unite(Date, Date, val, sep="")
#  Date Electricity
#1  190          23
#2  690          24
#3  790          34
#4  191          42
#5  691          27
#6  791          13
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("janv-90", "juin-90", "juil-90", "janv-91", 
"juin-91", "juil-91"), Electricity = c(23L, 24L, 34L, 42L, 27L, 
 13L)), .Names = c("Date", "Electricity"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: the month names need not all be of 4 letters @akrun. `substr` won't work there

Comment: @joel.wilson Have you checked it after settting the `Sys.setlocale`

Answer (score 0):

since your monts were in French, found a little long route, else we already have month names as constants in R like in `month.abb` or `month.names`

```
# first I create a look-up vector
month.abb.french <- c("janv", "fevr", "mars", "avril",
                      "mai", "juin", "juil", "aout", "sept",
                      "oct", "nov", "dec")

# extract the months
month <- unlist(strsplit(df$Date, "-"))[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
# similarily extract the years
year <- unlist(strsplit(df$Date, "-"))[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
# month
#[1] "janv" "juin" "juil" "janv" "juin" "juil"
# year
#[1] "90" "90" "90" "91" "91" "91"

df$newcol <- paste0(match(month, month.abb.french), year)
#      Date Electricity newcol
#1: janv-90          23    190
#2: juin-90          24    690
#3: juil-90          34    790
#4: janv-91          42    191
#5: juin-91          27    691
#6: juil-91          13    791
```